# Grails: display dynamic contents with using twitter bootstrap pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails, pagination

How can I display each content in twitter bootstrap pagination? I can only display the first content. I used   tag to display the contents but I don't know how to get all the element ids.

Here is the javascript code that get the element id to display it in pagination:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="bs-docs-example">
            <p class="well demo content1">
               Dynamic content here.
             </p>
             <p class="demo demo1"></p>
         </div>

                <!-- Demo time! -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var pageNumber = 0;
                    $('.demo1').bootpag({
                        total: '${count}',
                        page: 1

                        }).on("page", function(event, num){

                            $(".content1").html(document.getElementById("child")); // or some ajax content loading...
                            $(this).bootpag({total:  '${count}', maxVisible:  '${count}'});
                    }); 
                </script>


        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code the generates the dynamic data in gsp page:

```
<g:each  var="item" in="${faxDocument}">  
        <div id="child">
            <a href="#"><center><img src="data:image/png;base64, ${item} " width="850" height="1200" /></center></a>
    </div>

    </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think with twitter bootstrap you dont need no js at all, try to generate the pagination "by hand"  sth. like:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <g:each in="${1..count}" status="i" >
   <g:if test="${i == offset}>
     <li class="active"><a href="${createLink( controller:'', action:'', params:[]>">${i}</a></li>
   </g:if>
   <g:else>
     <li><a href="${createLink( controller:'', action:'', params:[]>">${i}</a></li>
   </g:else>
 </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @john for the help. I will use that solution.

Comment: hi @john, how about I will implement it like this: 
    <ul class="pagination">
       <g:each  var="item" in="${faxDocument}">  
          <li>  <a href="#"><center><img src="data:image/png;base64, ${item} " width="850" height="1200" /></center></a> </li>
      </g:each>
</ul>

I'm confuse how can I display the images in pagination.

Comment: whats insider ${item} = ? you should rather use the ressources for assets like images like <g:ressource dir="/" file="img.png" />

Comment: ${item} is a base64 String png image. I used this code to preview a png image:
<img src="data:image/png;base64, ${item} " width="850" height="1200" />

based on the requirements, we don't save images in **"images folder"** of grails app.

Comment: if we remove typos <code><ul class="pagination">
  <g:each in="${1..count}" status="i" >
   <g:if test="${i == offset}">
     <li class="active"><a href="${createLink(controller:'', action:'', params:[]}">${i}</a></li>
   </g:if>
   <g:else>
     <li><a href="${createLink( controller:'', action:'', params:[]}">${i}</a></li>
   </g:else>
 </g:each></code>

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to add the missing classes and tags via jQuery e.g.

```
// Fix pagination
// Wrap all direct children into a list element
$('ul.pagination >').wrap('<li class="page-item"></li>');

// add the missing class to the href tags
$('ul.pagination li a').addClass('page-link');

// Handle active element
$('span.currentStep').parent().addClass('active');
```